# JSON loading wrong object

Tags: android, mysql, json

I am trying to POST data into mysql using json. I have also used JSON for the login feature. The login works perfectly fine. The problem is on the loading activity. After i insert all the data and click the "Save" Button it takes me back to a previous activity and says "Login successful" which is only supposed to happen on the login activity. I checked all the layouts in case i referenced the wrong button for save but everything was the way it was supposed to be.

Login.java

```js
package com.example.bsc.barloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button mSubmit;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;


    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.2.101/webservice/login.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        // setup input fields
        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);




        // setup buttons
        mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);


        // register listeners
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                System.exit(0);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.login:
                new AttemptLogin().execute();
                break;


            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("System Attempting Login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String username = user.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User_id", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                        params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                    // save user data
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login.this);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
                    edit.putString("User_id", username);
                    edit.commit();

                    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Display_Menu.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null) {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

```html
package com.example.bsc.barloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Loading extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    public String[] SugarType;
    public int position =0;
    private EditText Units,FromWareHouse,ToWareHouse,DeliveryNumber,Transporter,NumberPlate;

    private DatePicker dp;
    private Button  bSave;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private static final String POST_COMMENT_URL = "http://192.168.2.101/webservice/adddispatch.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loading);
        bSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SaveDispatch);
        bSave.setOnClickListener(this);
        Units = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Units);
        FromWareHouse = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.FromWarehouse);
        ToWareHouse = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ToWarehouse);
        dp = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.Date);
        SugarType = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.TypeofSugar);
        Spinner spSugarType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSugarType);
        Transporter = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Transporter);
        DeliveryNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.DeliveryNumber);
        NumberPlate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.NumberPlate);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, SugarType);
        spSugarType.setAdapter(adapter);

        //setting up listener for the spinner
        spSugarType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
                position = index;
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });


    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new AddLoad().execute();
    }


    class AddLoad extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Loading.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Adding Load...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;

            String strSugarType = SugarType[position];;
            String strFromWareHouse = FromWareHouse.getText().toString();
            String strToWareHouse = ToWareHouse.getText().toString();
            String strUnits = Units.getText().toString();
            String strDate = dp.getDayOfMonth() + "/"
                    + (dp.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dp.getYear();
            String strDeliveryNumber = DeliveryNumber.getText().toString();
            String strTransporter = Transporter.getText().toString();
            String strNumberPlate = NumberPlate.getText().toString();


            //String post_dayt = dayt.getText().toString();

            //shared preferences store data about the current logged in user
            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Loading.this);
            String post_username = sp.getString("User_id", "");

            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User_id", post_username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SugarType", strSugarType));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Units", strUnits));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FromWarehouse", strFromWareHouse));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ToWarehouse", strToWareHouse));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Date", strDate));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DeliveryNumber", strDeliveryNumber));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Transporter", strTransporter));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("NumberPlate", strNumberPlate));


                Log.d("request!", "starting");

                //Posting user data to script
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        POST_COMMENT_URL, "POST", params);

                // full json response
                Log.d("Post Comment attempt", json.toString());

                // json success element
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Comment Added!", json.toString());
                    finish();
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    Log.d("Comment Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null){
                Toast.makeText(Loading.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: `After i insert all the data and click the "Save" Button it takes me back to a previous activity and says "Login successful" which is only supposed to happen on the login activity` because calling `finish()` in `Save` Button click. please explain what you want

Comment: As i mentiond I am trying to POST data into mysql using json.. in my app i had previously used JSON to connect to mysql database to login.. now i want to insert data on a different table but somehow it takes me to login feature and says "Successfully logged in".. i want it to insert strings from the edit text to the database and its giving me a json protocol used in a different part of the app

Comment: OKay i have fixed the problem. it was on the php webservice file